# show duplicated rows and create a now dataset in r

Tags: r, duplicates

I have this table.

```
data          pm10
2016-09-01    15.6
2016-09-02    16.8
2016-09-03    17.1
2016-09-04    15.4
2016-09-04    14.5    
2016-09-05    18.4
```

Now I what to find the duplicated rows (with the same date). Here it is the date 2016-09-04. 
I want to identify this rows, delete the wrong ones and create a new table containing all duplicates to have a overview of them. 
How to do that? Please no SQL.

Comment: Failure to read your mind: Define "wrong ones". (And while you're at it look at the `?duplicated` help page.) You might also do a search in SO for : `[r] duplicated`. This sort of question has been asked many times before.

Comment: "wrong ones" are the duplicated rows"

New, more precise question, below

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  data=c("2016-09-01", "2016-09-02", "2016-09-03", "2016-09-04", "2016-09-04", "2016-09-05"),
  pm10=c(15.6,16.8,17.1, 15.4,14.5,18.4)
)

df_unique <- df[which(duplicated(df$data)==F),]

df_duplicated <- df[which(duplicated(df$data)==T),]
```

Answer (score 0):

dummydata:

```
    df <- as.data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE, text='data          pm10
2016-09-01    15.6
2016-09-02    16.8
2016-09-03    17.1
2016-09-04    15.4
2016-09-04    14.5    
2016-09-05    18.4'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

base R:

```
noduplicates <- df[!duplicated(df$data),]
duplicates <- df[duplicated(df$data),]
```

dplyr:

```
 library(dplyr)
 noduplicates <- df %>% distinct(data, .keep_all = TRUE)
```